# Use of lambda in the following expression

Tags: python, lambda, odoo

While going developing OpenERP, I found the following piece of code

`'app_date': lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

I know what lambda is.My question is why use lambda?Why not just

`'app_date': time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`'app_date': time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` will evaluate the `time.strftime` immediately.  By wrapping it in a lambda, its execution is deferred until later (the time when you call the lambda).  Roughly speaking, the difference is between "the time when I defined this" and "the time when I am using this".  Look:

```
>>> d = {'a': time.time(), 'b': lambda: time.time()}
>>> d['a'], d['b']()
(1346913545.049, 1346913552.409)
>>> d['a'], d['b']()
(1346913545.049, 1346913554.518)
>>> d['a'], d['b']()
(1346913545.049, 1346913566.08)
```

I allowed some time to elapse in between each `d['a'], d['b']()`.  Note that `d['a']` is always the same: it is the time when I defined `d`.  `d['b']` is a function.  `d['b']()` (with parentheses) calls the function, which evaluates the time anew on each call, so it is different at each usage.

Also, this is nothing special about `lambda`.  Lambdas are just functions like any other.  I could do the same with:

```
def func():
    return time.time()
d = {'a': time.time(), 'b': func}
```

Comment: Indeed, and it is a common pitfall in default values for OpenERP models. Most OpenERP default values can be simple literal strings/integers/booleans, but datetime ones need to be wrapped in a callable, otherwise the default valye will always be the server startup date and time, and not the current time..

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk_(functional_programming).  I have only heard the term "thunk" in the context of performance-inspired lazy evaluation, but it may apply to this time-related example, as well.  Anybody know?